# How to enter date and time for a user on one line

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How do I put all of the below I have into one line so the user is able to enter at once?

So, instead of it popping up with a `Read-Host` every time they want to enter something in - it pops up once and states what you want to enter the date as..

So - "Please enter in FULL Date with time - ie 25 Oct 2012 9:00"

Also - if someone enters in a weird character, how do I let it error out?

```
$Day = $(Read-Host "Enter day of month")
if ($Day -eq ''){$Day = Get-Date -format dd}

$Month = $(Read-Host "Enter Month of Year")
if ($Month -eq ""){$Month = Get-Date -format MM}

$Year = $(Read-Host "Enter Year")
if ($Year -eq "") {$Year = Get-Date -format yy}

$Hour = $(Read-Host "Enter Hour")
if ($Hour -eq "") {$Hour = Get-Date -Format HH}

$Minute = $(Read-Host "Enter Minute")
if ($Minute -eq "") {$Minute = Get-Date -Format mm}

$Second = $(Read-Host "Enter Hour")
if ($Second -eq "") {$Second = Get-Date -Format ss}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
do
{
    $date= read-host "Please enter date & time (i.e.: '25/12/2012 09:00', '25 oct 2012 9:00'; date alone set time to 00:00):"

    $date = $date -as [datetime]

    if (!$date) {
        "Not A valid date and time"
    }
} while ($date -isnot [datetime])

$date
```

Comment: You're missing a trailing " from read-host prompt string but a good solution +1

Comment: @nimizen I fixed it and changed inside double quote to single one! Thanks!